# Remove special characters in a URL

Tags: url-rewriting, htaccess, security

I need a help to prevent special characters in URL & it should redirect to 404 error page, if anyone specifically entered characters. I tried a couple of ways through `.htaccess` but none of them worked.

Expected URL:

```
http://www.example.com/ar/shop-listing/health-beauty/
```

but still I can see the page if I entered like

```
http://www.example.com/ar/shop-listing/health-beauty~@/#$&&&%%$%3Cscript%3E/
```

Can anyone suggest a solution to approach this issue?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> http://www.example.com/ar/shop-listing/health-beauty~@/#$&&&%%$%3Cscript%3E/
> ```

In this particular URL, everything after the `#` (hash) is the *fragment identifier* and is not sent to the server by the browser, so cannot be blocked server-side in `.htaccess`.

The server only sees:

```
/ar/shop-listing/health-beauty~@/
```

If the `#` was to be removed from this URL then this would be a wholly invalid URL (because of the improperly encoded `%` chars) and the server will respond with a "400 Bad Request".

*Aside:* Not sure why WordPress would still resolve this URL to the "correct" URL? This is technically a different URL.

Rather than blocking special characters, it's probably much easier to *allow* a whitelist of characters in the URL-path. Most URL-paths will only consist of lowercase `a-z`, `-` (hyphen) and `/` (slash - path separator), so we could simply block the request if any other character is present in the URL-path. This could be implemented using the following mod_rewrite directive at the top of your `.htaccess` file, *before* the existing WordPress directives:

```
RewriteRule [^a-z/-] - [R=404]
```

If the URL-path contains any characters other than those mentioned then it will trigger a 404.

Note that this only checks the URL-path, not the query string part of the URL.